# 3.5 mm headphone jack -> bluetooth?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, productivity, headphone-jack

Would like to connect something to my PCs audio out headphone jack that will broadcast the audio via Bluetooth. I found a few [examples on amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003TC14QU) but not sure if there is a better product or way. Also, would I have to install any drivers for a solution like this?

I'm a newbie to this, any help is appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: Your question appears to essentially be asking for a shopping recommendation.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would I have to install any drivers for a solution like this?

You wouldn't need to install anything on the transmitting device.